# How to increase tasks queued per second?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to diagnose an under-performing airflow pipeline and am wondering what kind of performance I should expect out of the airflow scheduler in terms similar to "tasks scheduled per second".

I have few queued jobs and many of my tasks finish in seconds so I suspect the scheduler is the limiting component and it is my fault for having many quick tasks. Still, I would rather not rewrite my DAGs if it can be avoided.

What can I do to increase the rate at which the scheduler queues tasks?

---

#### Pipeline Details

[Here is what my current airflow.cfg looks like.](https://gist.github.com/7yl4r/7b7e90d1155337c0a31ad9e285a85e08)

I only have two dags running. One is scheduled every 5 min and the other is rarely triggered by the first. I am currently trying to backfill several years at this frequency, but may need to change my approach:

[image]

As for worker nodes: I currently have 4 fairly powerful servers running at less than 10% resource usage in disk, network, cpu, RAM, swap. Toggling 3 of the workers off has no impact on my task throughput and the server left on barely even registers the change in workload.

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of config values in your `airflow.cfg` that could be related to this.

Under `[core]`:

- [parallelism](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L75-L78): Total number of task instances that can run at once.
- [dag_concurrency](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L80-L81): Limit of task instances that can run per DAG run, may need to bump if you have many parallel tasks. Can override when defining a DAG.
- [non_pooled_task_slot_count](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L86-L88): Limit of tasks without a pool configured that can run at once.
- [max_active_runs_per_dag](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L90-L91): The maximum number of active DAG runs per DAG. If you're triggering runs manually or there's a backup of DAG runs scheduled with a short interval. Can override when defining a DAG.

Under `[scheduler]`:

- [schedule_heartbeat_sec](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L312-L315): Defines how often the scheduler runs, try it out with lower values.
- [min_file_process_interval](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L321-L322): Process each file at most once every N seconds. Set to 0 to never limit how often you process a file.

Under `[worker]`:

- [celeryd_concurrency](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.9.0/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L264-L268): Number of workers celery will run with, so essentially number of task instances a worker can take at once. Matching the number of CPUs is a popular starting point, but can definitely go higher.

Last one is only if you're using the `CeleryExecutor`, which I'd definitely recommend if you're looking to increase your task throughput.

Comment: Thanks for this nice summary of config values. I have been playing with some of them and not seen much change in task throughput. I have added a link to my airflow.cfg to my question.

Comment: Can you give an idea of how many DAGs you have, how often they run, and how many tasks they have? Perhaps it's worth watching scheduler logs as well to see if there's any bottlenecks (it does print stats on how long each DAG took to process every 30 seconds).

Comment: Also how many workers do you have? Just wondering how it compares to your estimated task throughput.

Comment: Those are good questions; I have updated my question to include details on my DAGs and workers. I know backfilling 5min frequency for decades is probably unrealistic, but I would still like to explore how to optimize scheduler performance. I didn't think to check the log; hopefully I will learn more from looking at that today. Thanks!